# Why FontAwesome social icons in <ul> are not working?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm noob and I'm following different tutorial to achieve my goal and  **the goal is to make animated social icons in the footer** and the problem is that the socials icons from FontAwesome are not working.

If i put them in < ul > they are not working but outside i can see them .-

How can i solve this to see them when I put them in < ul > ?

This is the code :
***HTML*** :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Contact us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilecontact.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/17fe744bb9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    
        <section>
         <div class="circle"></div>
         <header>
             <a href ="index.html" class="logo"> <img src ="logo.jpg"></a>
         
            
         </header>
      
       
     </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-box">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Name">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Email">
                <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Phone">
                <textarea placeholder="Message" class="field"></textarea>
                <button class="btn">Send</button>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<footer>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  
</ul>

</footer>
</html>
```

This is CSS:

```
    *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}


.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 100px;
}

.container:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: url("team.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(50px);
    z-index: -1;
}
.contact-box{
    max-width: 850px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

.left{
    background: url("team.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.right{
    padding: 25px 40px;
}

h2{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.field{
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.6);
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    transition: .3s;
}

.field:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

textarea{
    min-height: 150px;
}

.btn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #27ae60;
}

.field:focus{
    border: 2px solid rgba(30,85,250,0.47);
    background-color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 880px){
    .contact-box{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .left{
        height: 200px;
    }
}

footer {
    margin: o;
    padding: o;
    box-sizing:  border-box;

}

body footer {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;

}
ul 
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
}

ul li
{
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a .fa
{
    font-size: 6em;
    color: #222;

}
ul li ::before
{
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 6em;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:nth-child(1)::before
{
    content: '\f099';
    color: #1da1f2;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1da1f2;

}
ul li:nth-child(2)::before
{
    content: '\f09a';
    color: #07476f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1da1f2;

}
ul li:nth-child(3)::before
{
    content: '\f16d';
    color:  #f24f1d;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f2391d;

}
```

Comment: typo : `ul li ::before`

Comment: typo: `margin: o;` ...

Comment: thank's typo corrected but still not working, (tried on different browser)

Comment: lol well i will spend other 3 months to find out alone  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Icons were there, but they were not visible. So for your reference, I have given red color.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}


.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 100px;
}

.container::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: url("team.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(50px);
    z-index: -1;
}
.contact-box{
    max-width: 850px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.left{
    background: url("team.jpg") no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}

.right{
    padding: 25px 40px;
}

h2{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

h2::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 4px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.field{
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.6);
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.field:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

textarea{
    min-height: 150px;
}

.btn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #27ae60;
}

.field:focus{
    border: 2px solid rgba(30, 85, 250, 0.47);
    background-color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 880px){
    .contact-box{
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .left{
        height: 200px;
    }
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

body footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;

}
ul 
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
}

ul li
{
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a .fa
{
    font-size: 6em;
    color: #222;

}
ul li::before
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 6em;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:nth-child(1)::before
{
    content: '\f099';
    color: #1da1f2;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1da1f2;

}
ul li:nth-child(2)::before
{
    content: '\f09a';
    color: #07476f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1da1f2;

}
ul li:nth-child(3)::before
{
    content: '\f16d';
    color: #f24f1d;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f2391d;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Contact us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilecontact.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/17fe744bb9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <section>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"> <img src="logo.jpg"></a>


      </header>


      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-box">
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Name">
            <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Email">
            <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Phone">
            <textarea placeholder="Message" class="field"></textarea>
            <button class="btn">Send</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

  <footer>
    <!-- <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  
</ul> -->

    <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>

    <div style="color:red">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
      <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
      <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
    </div>
  </footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**found the solution** !

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Contact us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilecontact.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <section>
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo"> <img src="logo.jpg"></a>


      </header>


      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="contact-box">
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Name">
            <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Your Email">
            <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Phone">
            <textarea placeholder="Message" class="field"></textarea>
            <button class="btn">Send</button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>

  <footer>
  
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"> </i></a> </li>
</ul>
    </div>
  </footer>

</html>
```

CSS

```
 *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background: #000000;
    }
    ul{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
    }
    ul li{
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    ul li a{
        text-decoration: none;}
    ul li a .fa{
        font-size: 6em;
        color: #222;
    }
ul li a .fa:hover{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
    ul li:before{
        position: absolute;
      font-family: FontAwesome;
        top: -10px;
        left: 0;
        font-size: 6em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(1)::before{
        content: '\f099';
        color: #1da1f2;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #1da1f2;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(2)::before{
        content: '\f232';
        color: #25d366;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #25d366;
    }
    ul li:nth-child(3)::before{
        content: '\f16a';
        color: #ff0000;
        border-bottom: 4px solid #ff0000;
    }
    ul li:hover:before{
        height: 110%;
    }
```